# Why does $|\mathfrak N| = c$ imply $|\mathfrak M| = 2^c$? (Proof of uncountability of infinite $\sigma$-algebras)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, cardinals

Here's a proof I saw for the uncountability of infinite $\sigma$-algebras. This is also a problem in Rudin's RCA.

In several places, the author has used that if $|\mathfrak N| = c$, then $|\mathfrak M| = 2^c$. I'm unable to prove this. Could someone please help?

> *Proof attached for reference:*
> [image]

Comment: $\mathfrak N$ is a collection of disjoint subsets. But $\mathfrak M$ contains every possible countable union of these disjoint subsets (because it's a sigma algebra). So I think that provides an injective map from the set of subsets of $\mathfrak N$, to $\mathfrak M$. This may not solve the question, but it seems useful.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the **infinite case** (which is the harder one), all you need for this proof is:

> If $\mathfrak N$ is a countable collection of non-empty pairwise disjoint sets in the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak M$, then $|\mathfrak M| \geqslant 2^{|\mathfrak N|}$.

**Proof**: Let $\mathcal{P} (\mathfrak N)$ be the set of all subsets of $\mathfrak N$. Let $f: \mathcal{P} (\mathfrak N) \rightarrow \mathfrak M$ defined by $f(E) = \bigcup_{S \in E}S$.

Since $\mathfrak N$ is a countable, $E$ is countable and we have $f(E) = \bigcup_{S \in E}S \in \mathfrak M$.

Since  $\mathfrak N$ is a collection of non-empty pairwise disjoint sets, we have that $f$ is injective (one-to-one).

So, $|\mathfrak M| \geqslant 2^{|\mathfrak N|}$.$\square$

**Remark 1**:  For the **finite case**, we must first note that $\mathfrak M = \sigma(\mathfrak N)$ (which means that the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak M$ is generated by $\mathfrak N$). In fact, if $\mathfrak N$ is finite (resp. countable), any set in  $\mathfrak M$ is a finite (resp. countable) union of sets in $\mathfrak N$.

Then, we can either prove the finite case directly, or we can just use a slight variation of the result above (which also includes the countable case):

> If $\mathfrak N$ is a countable collection of non-empty pairwise disjoint sets in the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak M$ and $\mathfrak M = \sigma(\mathfrak N)$, then $|\mathfrak M| = 2^{|\mathfrak N|}$.

**Proof**: we define $f$ as in the previous proof. The $f$ is well-defined and injective. Now, since $\mathfrak M = \sigma(\mathfrak N)$, it is easy to show that $f$ is also surjective (onto). So, $|\mathfrak M| = 2^{|\mathfrak N|}$. $\square$

**Remark 2**: Here is the direct proof of the finite case:

**Direct Proof for the finite case**: Since $\mathfrak N$ is finite and the sets in $\mathfrak N$ are disjoint, it is easy to see that there are $2^{|\mathfrak N|}$ possible unions of sets in $\mathfrak N$. Each of them are in  $\mathfrak M$ and each set in $\mathfrak M$ is one of them. So, $|\mathfrak M| = 2^{|\mathfrak N|}$. $\square$

Comment: Could you explain what is meant by $\sigma(\mathfrak N)$? Also for the proof, I've attached in my post, are you sure that the first result suffices? I don't see how it handles the finite case.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor When I write $\mathfrak M = \sigma(\mathfrak N)$, it means the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak M$ is generated by $\mathfrak N$.  The finite case is handled in the  **Remark**.  I will edit the answer to make those points clearer.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor I have edited the answer and I have added more details. I hope it is clearer now.  It is not late for asking questions.  Your questions are welcome. Please, let me know if you have any further question regarding my answer.

Comment: Okay, got it! Just to make sure, whether $\mathfrak N$ is finite or countable, in both cases equality holds right?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor Yes, in both cases equality holds.